# How to solve an authentication error on Belboon webservice in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

This is what i've tried in VB.NET, but i always get an authentication error ("Unauthorized (user= transaction=1)"):

```
Dim s As com.belboon.api.BelboonHandler = New com.belboon.api.BelboonHandler
s.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
's.RequestEncoding = Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8
s.UseDefaultCredentials = False
's.PreAuthenticate = True
's.UserAgent = ": Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 4.0.20506)"
's.InitializeLifetimeService()
's.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = False

s.getAccountInfo()
```

There is only an example in PHP delivered by Belboon. I've tried this too, and it works fine:

```
define('WSDL_SERVER', 'http://api.belboon.com/?wsdl');
// SOAP options (http://de.php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapclient.php)
$config = array(
'login' => 'YOUR_LOGIN_NAME',
'password' => 'YOUR_WEBSERVICE_PASSWORD',
'trace' => true
);
try {
$client = new SoapClient(WSDL_SERVER, $config);
$result = $client->getAccountInfo();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
} catch( Exception $e ) {
```

But what might the auth error in VB.NET be caused by? The credentials are definitely the same in both examples...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got it myself. Like explained here:

https://intellitect.com/calling-web-services-using-basic-authentication/